# iOS building failed

Tags: ios, xcode4.5

This problem drives me nuts, I have followed the instructions from [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/how-to-test-your-apps-on-physical-ios-devices/)

Allthough my simulator working, on my real device I am getting this error

`Code Sign error: The identity 'com.apple.ubiquity.peer-uuid.F300F182-DEBA-49E2-XXXX-844DCBE14D85' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains`

Comment: You should change the Code Sign Certificate in the Build Settings

Comment: you need to get the developer profile and distribution profile from your apple developer account and install them in to your mac.So that you can run on the device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate installed in the application which is provided by tutplus is not matching to the provisional profile of your device so change the certificate to your own certificate which was signed to your provisional certificate of your device then the error will be removed

Comment: I have followed the process step by step numerous times, still getting this error

Comment: Do you created the certificate in developer account and created the provisional profile with your device UDID added???

Comment: You have to install the provisional certificate in your mac and in your device. drag the provisional certificate and your developer certificate to the xcode organizer. And make sure the provisional certificate is showing as Valid. If it is not showing as valid you have missed some thing. Check the process again

Comment: All this stuff has been done, I think that I am missing the real error, a key and certificate as mentioned by xcode. But how is supposed to be done?

Comment: You should create a certificate in you mac using key chain. after creating that certificate you mac will save the private key, then you should give that certificate to developer.apple.com then it will generate developer certificate which you have to install on your mac.

Comment: with out private key you will get the code sign error. It will work only when your private key and public key(which will be provided by developer.apple.com) will be combined.

Comment: There was a conflict with my private key, thanx for the help guys